# Spring Security: property placeholder for login-page url

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to put the url to my login-page in a properties-file and call this property in the xml-config.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="${login.url.login}" authentication-failure-url="${login.url.failure}" default-target-url="${login.url.succes}"
    always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <security:logout />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/spring/**" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAuthenticationProvider">
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="userAuthenticationProvider" class="com.security.services.implementations.CustomUserDetailsService"></bean>
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.security.services.encoders.PasswordEncoder"></bean>

<beans profile="qa">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/qa.properties" />
</beans>
<beans profile="dev">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/dev.properties" />
</beans>
<beans profile="test">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/test.properties" />
</beans>
```

with the following in the properties-file:

`login.url.login=https://www.......(url to login-page)`

When I deploy this, it gives the following error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'login.url.login' in string value "${login.url.login}?logout"

The properties-file is found correctly and every other property that is defined in this file is read as it should be. The only property that is read is this property.

If, on the other hand, I put the url hard-coded in the xml-config, everything goes fine. Is there any way to solve this problem with the url externalized in the properties-file?

Comment: Could you provide how you defined the placeholder? Or the whole context configuration file.

Comment: i've edited the question with the complete security-config

Comment: The placeholder is handled by the namespace support and not the property placeholder. This kicks in before the property placeholder is even being able to do something. Register it as a system property or manually configure every bean for the `form-login` (which is a pain) to get the normal processing from the property placeholders.